# RxJava - Use of Subjects

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, reactivex

I understand that the use of Subjects in the RxJava world are generally discouraged. Im trying to observe on property changes of an object which can easily be achieved with a subject. I know rx.net provides Observable.FromEvent() to easily handle this situation but I was wondering if their was a non-subject based Java alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that functionality through the `Observable.create` method:

```
Observable.create(emitter -> {
    PropertyObserver x = event -> emitter.onNext(event)
    yourObject.addObserver(x);
    // Set cancellable after adding observer, if the observable is
    //  disposed already it will properly remove the listener.
    emitter.setCancellable(() -> yourObject.removeObserver(x));
});
```

But you need to be aware that each time this observable is used it adds a new listener to the associated object. This can be avoided by applying the `share()` and `publish()` operators if multiple observers depend on the events of the object.

Answer (score 1):

Use `create` operator. Here give you a complete sample.

```
package xdean.stackoverflow.rx;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.ObservableEmitter;
import io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable;

public class Q47000589 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Property<Integer> p = new Property<>(1);
    Disposable d = p.listen().subscribe(i -> System.out.println("Listen: " + i));
    p.set(2);
    p.set(3);
    d.dispose();
    p.set(4);
    p.set(5);
  }

  public static class Property<T> {
    T value;
    List<ObservableEmitter<? super T>> emitters = new LinkedList<>();

    public Property(T value) {
      this.value = value;
    }

    T get() {
      return value;
    }

    void set(T t) {
      this.value = t;
      emitters.forEach(e -> e.onNext(t));
    }

    Observable<T> listen() {
      return Observable.create(e -> {
        emitters.add(e);
        e.onNext(value);
        e.setCancellable(() -> emitters.remove(e));
      });
    }
  }
}
```

And output is:

```
Listen: 1
Listen: 2
Listen: 3
```